# Doctrine2 subtract two datetimes

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm

So in my database I got a datetime field, filled with e.g. 2012-09-19 11:20:33.
Now I'm trying to fetch the datetime.

```
$blabla = $something->getDatetime();
```

After that I create a new DateTime, which represents the time now

```
$now = new \DateTime("now");
```

And after that I want to subtract them like this (but it doesn't work)?

```
$test1 = strtotime($blabla);
$test2 = strtotime($now);
$diff = $test2 - $test1; 
echo $diff;
```

My aim is to subtract the persisted datetime in the database from the time now...the result should be displayed in seconds...so 2012-09-19 11:22:22 - 2012-09-19 11:20:22 equals 120 (seconds).

I also tried to persist a unix timestamp into my database but unfortunately the field type timestamp doesn't exist.

Comment: The "perfect" solution for my issue would be to convert the datetime from the database and the time now to a unix timestamp and then subtract them...but i cant really manage it to work...

Comment: Really? Then it might be news for you that PHP has a manual for each class, for example the said `DateTime` type: http://php.net/datetime - I hope you're able to figure out the function on your own, if not, let us know! This by the way has nothing to do with Symfony2 or Doctrine in specific, you probably just looked in the wrong place.

Comment: Im trying it with ->getTimestamp()...but you seem quite mad, my good sir...:D

Comment: Yeah, directly from the Madhatters dept. :D For the Diff in seconds "Total number of seconds" (as you asked below), I'd suggest you open a feature request on php.net: https://bugs.php.net/ - It should be possible by default IMHO with `$diff->format()` at least, the formatting letter is missing IMHO. If you make a report, please leave a link here to it. -- http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the answer displayed in seconds, then just subtract the timestamps:-

```
$blabla = $something->getDatetime();
$now = new DateTime();
$seconds = $now->getTimestamp() - $blabla->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$blabla = $something->getDatetime();
$now = new \DateTime("now");
$diff = $now->diff($blabla);
```

Remember that $diff is a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object en you must use its methods and properties to get to the final desired result.

Comment: I tried it as you said...DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Perhaps $blabla is already a DateTime object, so try: $diff = $now->diff($blabla);

Comment: You could also try var_dump($blabla) to see what object it is.

Comment: Ok, this works! 

Any sugesstions how i can get the output to be displayed just in seconds? so that 1min 20sec would be 80sec?

Comment: use: ($diff->i * 60) + $diff->s